# Cant make a form write into a txt file using PHP

Tags: php, forms, file

Currently I have a form with the following code.

```
<form action="/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<h1>BasicForm 
    <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
</h1>
<label>
    <span>Your Nickname* :</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="It will appear in the file" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Your Email* :</span>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Message* :</span>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="The text that will appear in the file"></textarea>
</label> 
 <label>
    <span>Code* :</span>
    <input id="code" type="text" name="email" placeholder="The Code That we sent to your email" />
</label>    
 <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
</label>    
</form>
```

and in the same directory I have a php file welcome.php with the following code (I want this form to write the "message"..

```
<?php
   $var = $_POST['message'];
   file_put_contents("/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
?>
```

And yes i have a file called data.txt in the same directory.
All these files are in the same directory, I really don't know whats the problem, because it writes nothing. I've already given all the permissions to data.txt 
Maybe I am miswriting the path? Everything is allocated in a host..

Comment: Should `<input id="code" type="text" name="email"` rather be `<input id="code" type="text" name="code"` ?

Comment: I seriously doubt the path is `/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt`, more likely it will be something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt"`

Comment: yes it should, but thats not important now, i dont want to write that info into the file. Its just decorative. However thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems with path of your `data.txt` file.

Change from

```
file_put_contents("/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

into

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

**Note**: You must have permission to write on file.

**Update 1**

You can put absolute path of file.

```
file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

You can also add check file exists or not.

```
if( file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt") )
{
    file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
else
    echo 'file does not exits';
```

Comment: Nothing changes, still not writting. By the way ive more information, when I  fill the form and send it. It redirects me to /welcome.php . Dunno just for the record, maybe this info could be useful.

Comment: well i tried the first line u put in the first update and nothing changed, still not writting. Then i placed a data.txt file in the principal folder /, and changed the path to  




file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND); and still nothing     @Hassaan

Comment: make sure your web-user (mostly www-data when using apache2), has access to the directory you are trying to write to. What about $_POST. does it contain your message? is this path $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt" valid to your server?

Comment: Check the server-logs, to see what errors the php-error-log contains.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, finally i Used the same code ive given in the main post, but the directory in the php was wrong, so the working php is

```
    <?php
   $var = $_POST['message'];
    file_put_contents("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
?>
```